# Form_multiselect() only passing index value

Tags: php, arrays, forms, codeigniter

I have a `form_multiselect()` filled with an array:

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Tabstream Mobile Tracking 
   [1] => Hasoffer MAT Third Party Tracking 
   [2] => Appsflyer Third Party Tracking
   [3] => Grow Mobile Tracking ... 
)
```

The problem I am having is upon submit, it is pulling the index from the multiselect rather than the value. I need the value returned.

**uri:**

```
/../../..&tag_targets%5B%5D=1
```

**[1]** being the index for "Hasoffer MAT Third Party Tracking" rather than the string.

Comment: That's how `form_multiselect` and `form_dropdown` work. Keys are `value` attributes and values are the text content of the option. Just read the same array by index when you process the form.

Comment: If only there were a way to retrieve a value from an array based on its key. Alas!

Answer (score -1):

Given you have the `index`, it should be easy for you to obtain the `values`.

```
<?php
  $batman = $_POST['powers'];
  foreach($batman AS $key=>$power)
  {
     echo $power,";
  }
?>
```

Comment: But i'm filling the form through a mysql query, so these are distinct values pulled from a database, so I can't access them by the array index they are placed in.

Comment: What is the end goal, what is the process to reach that goal, that you are currently implementing and where is the problem. :) Be more concise.

Comment: The end goal is to search a database for items containing associated "tags" which are the values within this multiselect. The form is filled within my model which does a mysql pull, the results then sent into the box. Then submit calls my controller and that box pulls:

Comment: with                                                               if($this->input->get('tag_targets')){
   $this->data['tag_targets'] = $this->input->get('tag_targets');
   $tag_arr = $this->input->get('tag_targets');
}

Comment: Then that array $tags_arr is filled from the getter and sent to my model to compose a mysql search.

Comment: You are confused what you want. This is no-where mentioned in the OP.

Comment: But when I output the values within that array anywhere along the way... it is the index of what I selected rather than the value.